# How to redirect a command for a specific application

Tags: shell

For example, the `feh` program can delete the currently viewed image, presumably using the `rm` command at some point. Let's say that instead of deleting the file, we want to run a trash script, say `trash.sh`. Is there anyway of running `feh` but tricking it into running `trash.sh` every time it calls `rm`?

Comment: It is exceedingly unlikely that a program, like `feh`, would be running the system `rm` command.

Comment: Use the program exclusively on temporary copies of files? Unbind the `Ctrl`+`Delete` action? As terdon says, it's unlikely that it calls the external `rm` command for removing images.

Comment: Most programs ultimately delete files using the `unlink(2)` system call. It is *possible* to intercept this using [function interposition](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ld_preload-trick-what-is), but that's almost never the correct answer (and it may not be 100% effective, and may have lots of edge cases around properly dealing with temporary files, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the sources of `feh` and run an arbitrary script instead of `unlink()` system call in `C` language, then compile new code:

```
git clone https://github.com/derf/feh.git
cd feh
cat<<EOF > trashbin.patch
--- src/filelist.c  2023-09-18 23:19:53.444892742 +0200
+++ src/filelist_new.c  2023-09-18 23:19:11.293556737 +0200
@@ -112,7 +112,11 @@
 
 gib_list *feh_file_rm_and_free(gib_list * list, gib_list * l)
 {
-   unlink(FEH_FILE(l->data)->filename);
+   //unlink(FEH_FILE(l->data)->filename);
+    char command[255];
+    sprintf(command, "/usr/local/bin/trashbin.sh %s", FEH_FILE(l->data)->filename);
+    system(command);
+    
    return(feh_file_remove_from_list(list, l));
 }

EOF
patch src/filelist.c < trashbin.patch
make
sudo make install
```

Then, create:

```
/usr/local/bin/trashbin.sh
```

with what you want, like

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p ~/.local/trashbin
/bin/mv -- "$@" ~/.local/trashbin
```